# Is "landlord" used for female as well?

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

I hear that the term "landlord" is used mostly for male. But is it also used for female? If not, what is a better word for expressing female owner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While you can certainly use the feminine form "landlady" if you want to be specific about their gender, this is an example of a word that's generally used regardless of the person's gender, that is to say, "landlord" no longer implies "*male* landowner". From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landlord):

> A landlord is the owner of a house, apartment, condominium, land or real estate which is rented or leased to an individual or business, who is called a tenant (also a lessee or renter). When a juristic person is in this position, the term landlord is used. Other terms include lessor and owner. The term landlady may be used for women owners, and lessor applies to both genders.

From [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/landlord):

> Men and women can both be landlords, although you can also call a female landlord a landlady. The concept of a landlord goes back to feudalism — the lord part comes from "Lord of the Manor."

Comment: Thanks. So then which is more polite or less rude for female?

Comment: @Blaszard You can avoid the issue entirely by using the term _"property owner"_ or _"landowner"_. In a legal document, _"lessor"_ will suffice.

Comment: I don't think there's a politeness element, @Blaszard  it depends. In general, English tends to be moving away from gendered terms towards either non-gendered versions (stewardess --> flight attendant) or towards using the same term for both genders (actor/actress --> actor or performer). Some of it is also a matter of personal preference.